# CFile::modeCreate not working as advertised

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

```
CFile   file;

CFileException fe;

if (file.Open(strPath, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeReadWrite | CFile::typeBinary, &fe) )
{
}
```

This doesn't work. The file path provided by strPath already exist but it will not open this file and returns with error code 5. If I do remove the `CFile::modeCreate`flag than the file is opened fine. The documentation says if the file already exists 'CFile::modeCreate' will attach itself to it and truncate it's to zero but in reality it never opens the file in the first place. Is there an issue with my call?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this. The problem was that the file had 'ready only' attribute set. I changed it to normal before I open it and that fixed it.

```
SetFileAttributes(strPath, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
```